# Geometric Realization of Standard Combinatorial $n$-Simplex is Standard Topological $n$-Simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex, simplicial-complex, geometric-realization

Let $\Delta$ be the simplex category with objects $[n]=\{0,...,n\}$, $n\geq 0$, and morphisms ordering preserving functions $[n]\rightarrow [m]$. Then let the standard categorical $n$-simplex be $Hom_{\Delta}(\bullet,[n])$, and is a simplicial set.

It is well known that the geometric realization of a categorical $n$-simplex is the standard topological $n$-simplex, but I can't seem to find a proof of this fact.

**Question:** Why is the geometric realization of a categorical $n$-simplex the standard topological $n$-simplex?

Comment: take a look at section 4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4221.pdf)

Comment: This seems to be given in example 4.3, but it says: "We encourage the reader to
explore this example on his or her own, noting that all of the degenerate simplices wind up tucked away within actual faces," but this is precisely my point of confusion

Comment: It's on p. 9 of the book by Goerss and Jardine.